# Interrupting Busy Workers in Parallel Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I just started running my Julia code on a cluster that has multiple cores, and so have changed my code to try and take advantage of this.  I launch julia with `julia -p 12`.  However, I consistently get an error that busy workers are being interrupted.

For this code, I have the master process create an `Train` array of types called a `ResultTable`.  I want to perform a function `gamerunner`, which takes as input a `ResultTable` and returns an `Int`.

For my first attempt, I tried `result=pmap(gamerunner,Train)`

The data are of the correct size, but an error of

> "WARNING: Forcibly interrupting busy workers ArgumentError("stream is
>   closed or unusable")"

was returned.

I was not sure what to do, so I tried

```
@sync result=pmap(gamerunner,Train)
```

and

```
@sync begin
result=pmap(gamerunner,Train)
end
```

which gave the same error.  Then I saw in the documentation that `@sync` doesn't say it works with `pmap`, so I decided to try `@parallel` instead

```
@sync begin
@parallel for i=1:size(Train)[1]
Train[i].result=gamerunner(Train[i])
end
end
```

and got the error

> "error in running finalizer: InterruptException() WARNING: Forcibly
>   interrupting busy workers ArgumentError("stream is closed or
>   unusable")"

Finally, I thought that since I had read a lot about `fetch`, maybe I had to do that to get it to work, so I tried

```
@parallel for i=1:size(Train)[1]
Train[i].result=gamerunner(Train[i])
end
for i=1:size(Train)[1]
fetch(Train[i].result)
end
```

and that gave me the error

> "WARNING: Forcibly interrupting busy workers WARNING: Unable to
>   terminate all workers"

I am getting more confused.  Your help is greatly appreciated.

### Edit

Example from the comments:

```
addprocs(2)
@everywhere function foo(test) sleep(2) end
Train=Matrix(0,1)
for i=1:60
  Train=[Train;0]
end
pmap(foo,Train)
```

Comment: `@sync` doesn't do anything with `pmap` because it doesn't return until all of the workers are done, meaning that it's unnecessary. That said, I have no idea why your workers are being interrupted.

Comment: Can you post a full runnable example? Some kind of minimal example which reproduces the error? This is impossible to debug without an example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply:  Here's an example:

`@everywhere cd("//home/aesche/")
@everywhere include("foo.jl")
Train=Matrix(0,1)
for i=1:60
    
         
Train=[Train;0]
      
end

pmap(foo,Train)`

foo.jl:
`function foo(test)
sleep(2)
end`

This returns:
error in running finalizer: InterruptException()
WARNING: Forcibly interrupting busy workers
ArgumentError("stream is closed or unusable")

Comment: I don't know what's in foo.jl.

Comment: foo.jl is `function foo(test) sleep(2) end`.  However, I did another test, and deleted the @everywhere commands and the pmap command, and it gives the same error.

Comment: I don't know if it's important, but I am running this on a cluster through a submitted job, and I believe the error message occurs on exit.  I reproduced the error once on my laptop after running some code and using exit(), but could not reproduce it consistently. (However, I can only run 1 worker on my laptop)

Comment: I think this is a cluster setup issue and not a code issue. I ran your example and was not able to reproduce the issue. Maybe someone [at the Julia Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/) can help diagnose the issue, but I am going to vote to close this unless you can get an example that is able to reproduce this (not a dig at you, just the site rules!). If it was a code issue, multiple processes even locally would cause the issue, which is why I think it must be with the cluster communication. Hopefully that helps a bit!